# template class instance receiving another instance of the same template class of different type

Tags: c++, templates

How can a template class instance receive another instance of the same template class of different type as an argument to some of its function member? (It's hard for me to express my question in simpler way and I'm so sorry for that.)

Here is a working code. I created a class and I named it MyClass. It accepts same template class of the same type(which is int) on its operator= and operator+ member functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class MyClass {
protected:
  T __val;
public:
  MyClass();
  MyClass(T val): __val(val) {}
  void operator= (const MyClass<T>& r)
  {
    __val = (T)r.__val;
  }
  const MyClass<T>& operator+ (const MyClass<T>& r)
  {
    return *(new MyClass<T>(__val + (T)r.__val));
  }
  T retval() {return __val;}
};

int main()
{
  MyClass<int> myclass1(1);
  MyClass<int> myclass2(2);
  MyClass<int> myclass3 = myclass1 + myclass2;
  cout << myclass3.retval() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I typecasted __val members of arguments for operator= and operator+ for the following purpose:

```
int main()
{
  MyClass<int> myclass1(1);
  MyClass<double> myclass2(2.5);
  MyClass<int> myclass3 = myclass1 + myclass2;
  cout << myclass3.retval() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

obviously I'll get an error. I cannot pass myclass2 as an argument to operator+ of myclass1 simply because `MyClass<int>::operator+` wants `MyClass<int>` argument, and not `MyClass<double>`. I know that I can overload another operator+ that accepts `MyClass<double>`, but I also want to do it with other number types such as float, single, etc. Making overloaded functions for all of them makes my code bigger, which I obviously don't want to happen.

What do I have to change from MyClass to make my second main function work?

Comment: `return *(new` -- NONONONONONONDONTWHYNOSTOP.

Comment: Also, `__names` like that are reserved for the implementation, don't use them.

Comment: Another chapter of the Java++ reference manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a template member `operator+`. Also, it should return a value, not a reference:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass 
{
 public:
  template <typename T2>
  MyClass operator+ (const MyClass<T2>& r) const { return _val + r.retval(); }

  T retval() const {return _val;}

  // as before
};
```

Note that this will return a value of the same type as the LHS in an expression involving `operator+`. Note that it would be a better idea to implement `operator+` as a non-member binary operator. But you have to implement some compile-time logic to determine the return type:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
MyClass< ?? > operator+(const MyClass<T1>& lhs, const MyClass<T1>& rhs)
{
  return lhs.retval() + rhs.retval();
}
```

where `??` should be replaced by a compile construct to pick a type based on `T1` and `T2`. Presumably this would be one of those two types. This is a C++11 example:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const MyClass<T1>& lhs, const MyClass<T1>& rhs)->decltype(lhs.retval()+rhs.retval())
{
  return lhs.retval() + rhs.retval();
}
```

This has the advantage that the return type is determined independent of what is on the LHS or RHS.

Comment: "It's throwing error" is not a very useful description of what happens. Reading the error message may provide an indication of what's wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest type traits for determining the result of adding a T to a T1.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I think I'm getting closer into it, but I'm still getting an error. Compiler says `error: passing 'const MyClass<double>' as 'this' argument of 'T MyClass<T>::retval() [with T = double]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] return (__val + r.retval());` What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Casting has stronger precendence than the dot, i.e. instead of

```
(T)r.__val
```

you have to write

```
(T) (r.__val)
```

Better, use `static_cast`.
Hence, define `operator +` like

```
template<class S>
MyClass<T> operator+ (const MyClass<S>& r) {
   return MyClass<T>(__val + (static_cast<S> (r.__val)) );
}
```

Or don't use explicit casting at all:

```
template<class S>
MyClass<T> operator+ (const MyClass<S>& r) {
   return MyClass<T>(__val + r.__val);
}
```

It would be probably better to make retval return a const T &, use retval () in the implementation of operator +, and make operator + a non-member non-friend:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
private:
  T m_val;
public:
  MyClass(T val): m_val(val) {}
  const T & retval () const {return m_val;}
};

template<class T1, class T2>
auto operator+ (const MyClass<T1>& r1, const MyClass<T2> & r2)
-> MyClass < std::remove_const < std::remove_reference <
   decltype ( r1.retval () + r2.retval () ) 
> > > {
    return r1.retval () + r2.retval ();
}
```

Comment: `__val` is protected, so `r.__val` would be inaccessible if `S` and `T` are different types.

Comment: It would be probably better to make `retval` return a `const T &`, use `retval ()` in the implementation of `operator +`, and make `operator +` a non-member non-friend.

Comment: I agree. I used `retval()`, but left it returning by value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like:

```
template<typename _Ty> MyClass<T> operator+ (const MyClass<_Ty>& r) {
   return MyClass<T>(__val + (static_cast<_Ty> (r.__val)) );
}
```

to provide a member function. But to more generally support it do like:

```
template<typename _T,typename _Ty> MyClass<_T> operator+ (const Myclass<_T>& p,const MyClass<_Ty>& r) {
       return MyClass<T>(p.__val + (static_cast<_T> (r.__val)) );
    }
```

Unfortunately for that you have to declear `__val` as public